# How to read the csv file as per header and print the values as per header

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have below csv file . How can i read line by line as per header and print the values

```
EmpId,EmpName,Age
1,X,21
2,Y,22
3,Z,23
```

I am trying to run below code and trying to print all the 3 columns

```
file = pd.read_csv('File.csv',names=[EmpId,EmpName,Age], delimiter=',')

for line in file:
    EmployeeID = EmpID (I want to assign value of EmpId to this variable )
    print(EmployeeID)
```

Example: as per my for loop when i am reading first line i want to print EmployeeID = 1

Comment: `EmployeeID = line.EmpId`?

Comment: Yes , As i have 3 lines in csv file and when i am running for loop for 3 times in each loop i want to read my 3 column values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several methods:

1. If you only want the employeeId you can do this

```
for EmployeeID in file.EmpId:
    # EmployeeID contains the id
    ...
```

2. If you want to iterate over the rows and not lose the information of other columns

```
for index, row in file.iterrows():
    EmployeeID = row["EmpId"]
    # You can access to others columns by row[col]
    ...
```

But keep in mind that in general you shouldn't iter over the rows, look at this discussion: [iterrows performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues). You might have no choice but try to see if you can implement vectorization or use [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Example apply to print the rows and perform some things:

```
def rowFunction(row):
    EmployeeId = row["EmpId"]
    print(row)
    ...
    return ...

file.apply(lambda row: rowFunction(row), axis=1)
```

Although apply is in general used to perform some calculation, and should return something.

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot of methods

```py
file = pd.read_csv('File.csv',names=['EmpId','EmpName','Age'], delimiter=',')
print(file.EmpId)
```

If u want to use the loop:

```
for line in file.values:
    print(line[0])  # 0: EmpId, 1:EmpName, 2:Age ...
```

or

```
for i in file.EmpId:
    print(i)
```

or

```
for i in file.EmpId.values:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @Thanks a lot for the reply. But i am getting 3 times same output [1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3] 
;
But i should be getting only once  :[1 2 3]

Answer (score 0):

```
# pandas.read_csv return pandas.DataFrame object, so df is a more common variable name
df = pd.read_csv('File.csv',names=[EmpId,EmpName,Age], delimiter=',')

#iterrows() is a good function to iteration rows in DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    EmployeeID = row['EmpID']
    print(EmployeeID)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Thanks!